# Linux Copy user's permission to another user

Tags: centos, chmod

The server is CentOS, the user is named `dev_admin`.

Now I added a new user `ops_admin` and 
I want to **copy `dev_admin`'s permission to `ops_admin`.**

I tried the following command as root:

```
useradd ops_admin
usermod -g dev_admin ops_admin   // add ops_admin to group dev_admin
```

As `dev_admin`:

```
chmod g=u /path/to/file  // copy user's permission to group.
```

when I tried to run the file, the result was

```
as user ops_admin /etc/init.d/command
```

the result is unexpected,  it ask for password and after typing the password, I got `ops_admin is not in the sudoers` (something like this).

As user `dev_admin`, it was fine.

How can I get this working?

Comment: What do you mean with your last sentence "when I tried to run the file it was always ops_admin is not in the sudoers."? Can you state it more clearly?

Comment: @kira thank for your reply.  the result was unexpected. first, it require typing in password to run,  also, it cannot run the command, but shows  " ops_admin" is not in the sudoers.

Comment: Only the owner or root can chmod files.

Comment: Permissions are not an attribute of a user but an attribute of files / directories. You can't "copy" them to a different user. You can have different logins for the same uid. You can have multiple users in a group and grant access based on the group permissions or you can use privilege seperation with a tool like "sudo". The command 'as' runs the gnu assembler on most linux systems - "as user..." will result in file not found errors. I have no idea what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Unix permissions and `/etc/sudoers` rules are completely unrelated.

You need to add a rule in `/etc/sudoers` (e.g. with `visudo`) that allows either user `ops_admin` or all members of group `dev_admin` to run some or all commands as root.

e.g. to allow ops_admin to run all commands as root:

```
ops_admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

or to allow all members of group dev_admin to run all commands as root:

```
%dev_admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

These are just examples.  I advise you not to just blindly copy-paste them into your `/etc/sudoers` file but to think very carefully about what commands user ops_admin or group dev_admin really need to run as root and give access to only required commands.

if there is already a rule for *user* dev_admin, maybe it would be best to copy that rule and edit it so that it is for user ops_admin.

Finally, note that if user ops_admin was already logged in when you added them to group dev_admin, they'll need to logout and log back in again (or use `newgrp`) in order for that change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks.  I am try to avoid      %dev_admin ALL=(ALL) ALL